# Book suggestions for Contact manifold and legendrian knots

Tags: book-recommendation, knot-theory, contact-topology

Can any one suggest some basic books for reading contact manifold and legendrian knots???

I tried some survey notes but I can't move after a stage because I need more definition from some papers. 
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 2):

http://people.math.gatech.edu/~etnyre/preprints/papers/oblec.pdf

http://people.math.gatech.edu/~etnyre/preprints/papers/legsur.pdf

Ozbagci-Stipsicz *Surgery on Contact 3-manifolds and Stein Surfaces*

Geiges *An Introduction to Contact Topology* (slightly more advanced than the other sources in my opinion)

Typically, these all require some basic differential topology (at the level of Guillemen-Pollack) and probably some familarity with a book such as Rolfsen or Gompf-Stipsicz for the basics of 3 and 4 manifold topology.